# How does Repercussion interact with Solphim, Mayhem Dominus?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

With [Repercussion](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Repercussion) and [Solphim, Mayhem Dominus](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Solphim%2C%20Mayhem%20Dominus), if I deal 3 damage to a creature with [Lightning Bolt](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Lightning%20Bolt) and Dominus doubles that, does it get doubled again when Repercussion deals 6 damage to the creature's controller?

Comment: Related - https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/37985/does-deflecting-palm-cause-furnace-of-rath-to-activate-twice same question different examples.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Correct, Repercussion would deal 12 damage to the creature's controller.**

Solphim applies a replacement effect to noncombat damage. Replacement effects can apply only once to any given event, so Ligthning Bolt will deal 6 damage to the target creature, causing Repercussion to deal 6 to its controller.

> 614.5. A replacement effect doesn’t invoke itself repeatedly; it gets only one opportunity to affect an event or any modified events that may replace that event.

However, the damage from Repercussion is its own event which Solphim can replace again, for a total of 6 damage to the targeted creature from Lightning Bolt and 12 damage to the creature's controller from Repercussion.

Comment: This is correct but could be worded better. There are people who will stop reading after the first paragraph, figuring they have gotten their answer and the rest explains it and saying "causing Repercussion to deal 6 to its controller." could be misleading.

Comment: @Andrew I would suggest that's only a real problem for people who not only stop reading after the first paragraph, but also skip the first, bolded line. I'd wager to say those are very few people indeed.